# How to show advertisment in embedded video in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, video, embed

I have created an embedded video like this:

```
<object id="add" width="425" height="350" > 
<param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/V7g4e5m5aRc&autoplay=1" /> 
<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/V7g4e5m5aRc" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="250" height="250" autostart="false"/> 
</object>
```

It plays video very smoothly, but I want to play a fixed **advertisement video (same as given example but different src)**   before the video plays, just like on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means good with javascript but I would do the following. First of all you can use the iframe api and check when your iframe (youtube video) changes its state. This is an example: (check out https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference for more)

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('videoDiv', {
        videoId: 'V7g4e5m5aRc',
      events: {
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}
```

Now you can check the even and do further actions:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
     // MY FUNCTION
  }
}
```

You can also stop the video and display your other in a popup. Using for example http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/.

```
<a href="//www.youtube.com/embed/ID" class="video_layer"></a>

$('.video_layer').colorbox({iframe:true});}
```

Maybe there are better solutions but this was the first "workaround" which came to my mind.